# issues with using variable pattern to control plane angle of feature

Tags: solidworks

two different problems.  first, I create a feature by creating a sketch for it on a plane that is defined using an angle.  whenever I update some part of the part, it seems, the name I've given to the angle resets.  this is a problem because I'm referencing the name of that angle in the pattern table for a variable pattern.  so it no longer works.  I have realized I should be able to solve this by just leaving the name with it's default values, but it looks like this is a bug.  second, I tried creating a simplified construction to help with this question, creating a part with a feature based off a sketch drawn on a plane whose angle I then tried to change.  and it just didn't work.[image]

edit:  found the following.  maybe it has all my answers???  https://www.design-point.com/resource/blog/winter-challenge-create-snowflake-using-solidworks-patterns/